# En una base de datos en la que personas están agrupadas en una misma tabla indistintamente, ¿cómo seleccionar dos tipos de personas?

Tags: sql, mysqli

Tengo este trabajo de la escuela y he intentado distintas formas de llegar a la solución del ejercicio C. He intentado con subconsultas y siempre percibo un error como el de "¿Cómo haría que compositor_id sea igual a PId y a la vez PId sea igual a Productor_Id.

No debo usar ningún manejador y por eso tengo la duda, he intentado tanto que ya me harté y quise ver si había alguien que me pudiese ayudar por aquí... :(
Esto es lo que tengo

```
SELECT Personas.Nombre

FROM  Personas P, Canciones C, Discos D, Canciones-Discos CD

WHERE P.PId = D.Compositor_ID AND C.CId = CD.CId AND CD.DcID = D.DcID AND D.Compositor_ID = (SELECT Compositor_ID 
                                          
                             FROM Personas P, Canciones C, Discos D, Canciones-Discos CD 
                              WHERE P.PId = D.Compositor_ID AND C.CId = CD.CId AND CD.DcID = D.DcID Personas.Nombre = Francisca Valenzuela);
```

Es una sintaxis didáctica (Lo digo por los joins solo especificados)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece que no tienes idea de SQL. Sugiero que te enfoques en aprender la sintaxis básica, con consultas más simples. Ya luego vendrán consultas más complejas. Es como querer correr sin saber caminar... lo bueno es que la sintaxis básica la aprendes en un pequeño rato. El Internet está lleno de ejemplos, incluso si navegas un poco por el [tag sql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) acá mismo, verás muchos ejemplos.

Comment: La pregunta esta bien formulada. No merece votos negativos. Sin embargo, deberias estudiar sobre sql. La forma en que escribiste el JOIN es totalmente incorrecta. Si luego de leer sobre eso, seguis con dudas, seria mejor que hagas una pregunta respecto a eso. Resolverte la consulta, sin que entiendas como se llega a eso, no va a servirte de nada.

Comment: Es que esa sintaxis usada es didáctica, ya que sé como se hace un join, sin embargo, en el salón de clase lo usamos así, es como tipo pseudocódigo

Comment: En StackOverflow, sin embargo, solemos publicar código que funciona al ejecutarlo en el motor. Si conoces la sintaxis de SQL, entonces, corrige las consultas que has publicado hasta donde puedes llegar, para ver si así podemos ver cual es el problema que estás teniendo para alcanzar el objetivo.

Comment: Ya lo hice, agradecería mucho tu ayuda, en serio estoy estresado

Comment: Estaba a punto de escribir una respuesta, pero no puedo hacerlo antes que leas esto: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4152/21  Un saludo.

Comment: Lo que yo no entiendo es cómo de una misma tabla que es la de Personas, puedo sacar dos valores diferentes al mismo tiempo como lo son el nombre del compositor y el de la compositora para poder solucionar el problema

Comment: Lo leeré, muchas gracias

Comment: Tene en cuenta que no conocemos tu sintaxis didactica, entonces no podemos contestar algo que no es conocido. a que te referis con seleccionar dos valores diferentes? estan en diferentes filas? entonces usarias un or o un in....

Comment: Estarán en las mismas filas, al momento de hacer la junta, en ese momento habrá dos Personas.Nombre, ya que habrá uno por Productor_ID y otro por Compositor_ID que son los dos nombres que están en la misma tupla.
Una disculpa, no he usado mucho Stack Overflow pero ya corregí la sintaxis

Comment: Si estan en dos columnas distintas, entonces tienen nombre de columna distinto, o segun el motor, por mas que tengan el mismo nombre, tiene tabla.campo distintos, por lo tanto, se puede buscar con un where de igual forma que otro. Lo que pasa es que tu pregunta sigue sin ser clara.. no vamos a traducir el enunciado... traducilo a lo que se necesita, y pregunta sobre eso...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a corregir primero el hecho que escribes SQL con sintaxis de *join* implícito, qué es confusa y era como se escribían las consultas hace 30 años. En el estándar SQL'92, se introdujo la sintaxis de *join explícito*, que es la recomendada y, como puedes intuír, mi preferida.

En un *join explícito* se utiliza la palabra `join`, que puede ir acompañada de `inner`, `left outer`, `right outer` o `full outer`. Si estas se omiten `inner` es el default y se específica la condición de dicho join como parte de la cláusula.

Entonces, si vamos a incluir `discos` y `disqueras` en una hipotética consulta, podríamos escribirla así:

```
select   disquera.nombre as nombre_disquera
       , discos.nombre as nombre_disco
  from discos
       inner join disquera on disquera.dqId = discos.dqId
```

Luego, a tu duda principal.

La tabla `Personas` está relacionada con `Discos` (como productor) y `Canciones` (como compositor).

Supongamos que queremos listar todas las canciones de todos los discos, con el nombre del productor y el nombre del compositor. Ambos nombres vienen de la tabla `Persona`, y lo que hacemos es incluir a esta tabla dos veces en la consulta, una vez *actuará* como persona compositora (de una canción) y la otra vez como persona productora (de un disco). Para lograrlo, le ponemos alias distintos a cada aparición de la tabla, de manera que podamos referirnos a ella sin ambigüedad.

Tenemos que involucrar también a la tabla `Canciones-discos`, que tiene la relación de muchos a muchos entre esas tablas.

```
select   Discos.Nombre Disco
       , Canciones.Nombre Cancion
       , productor.Nombre NombreProductor
       , compositor.Nombre NombreCompositor
  from Discos
       inner join `Canciones-Discos` AS cd on cd.DcId = Discos.DcId
       inner join Canciones on Canciones.CId = cd.CId
       inner join Personas AS productor on productor.PId = Discos.Productor_PId
       inner join Personas AS compositor on compositor.PId = Canciones.compositor_PId
```

Como ves, he utilizado los alias `compositor` y `productor`, lo cual añade claridad a la consulta. Para definir los alias, se puede omitir la palabra `AS`, y yo regularmente lo hago. Aquí la he dejado para que quede más clara la intención.

Si quisieramos listar solamente los discos y canciones del compositor `'Juan Pérez'`, entonces, añadimos una cláusula `where` con la condición apropiada, por ejemplo:

```
 where compositor.Nombre = 'Juan Pérez'
```

Y si queremos restringir más la búsqueda e incluir solamente aquellos discos y canciones de este compositor que se hayan publicado antes del 2018, añadimos una segunda condición, unida con el operador `AND` para que nos devuelva solo las filas que cumplen con ambas condiciones:

```
 where compositor.Nombre = 'Juan Pérez'
   and year(Discos.`Año`) < 2018
```

Considero que, si lees con atención y comprendes lo explicado, tienes lo necesario para resolver tu ejercicio.

Comment: El problema es que Compositores y Productores no tienen una tabla propia, esos datos están en Personas nada más

Comment: Lo sé, ¿has leído mi respuesta?

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias, lo resolveré

Comment: Vaya, soy muy bobo, muchas gracias por la paciencia y por tal explicación, yo no sabía que eso se podía hacer en SQL

Comment: Hombre, has caído en la cuenta. Me alegra ser de ayuda y que bueno que has aprendido algo nuevo hoy. :)